# CoordinatorLayout doesn't hide the actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is driving me nuts. I have been trying to make this work for two days, and no progress has been made. I want to have an app bar that hides when I scroll the `ViewPager` down, and shows when I scroll `ViewPager` up, and this appears to be the standard way of doing it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/posts_pager_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/posts_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The viewpager contains a bunch of fragments which contain a listview in each. I'm using appcompat and design of version 22.2.0.

I have compared my code with the code here: git@github.com:slidenerd/Android-Design-Support-Library-Demo.git, and found no major difference. Could someone please help? Thanks. I wouldn't post this if I haven't exhausted all my options.

Comment: Don't you need a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: Can you clarify "scrolling up/down" your ViewPager? Do you mean swiping left and right in your ViewPager or scrolling up and down in your ListView?

Comment: @MarkusRubey Scrolling up / down would be in the ListView in the ViewPager. Scrolling left and right which switches the the current item in the ViewPager works as intended now.

Comment: I did some testing and entered an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing and here are my findings:

The layout you had originally (without the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`) was closer.  I tweaked your layout and tested with it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/posts_pager_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/posts_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So here are the major points:

- `CoordinatorLayout` has to have an `AppBarLayout` and one other child layout.
- `AppBarLayout` has to have a `Toolbar` and/or a `TabLayout`.
- The `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` attribute goes on the `Toolbar` and/or the `TabLayout`.

  Whichever layout has `scrollflags` (or both) will scroll out of view.  So I don't know if you wanted the `Toolbar` to scroll and *not* the `TabLayout`, but either way you can control the behavior.
- You can't use a `ListView` as your scrolling view.  Even inside your `ViewPager` fragment. Adding the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute made no difference.

  You have to use a `RecyclerView` or a `NestedScrollView`.  Oddly, I didn't need the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute on the `RecyclerView`.  And this was inside the `Fragment` subclass for the `ViewPager`.

Comment: > You have to use a RecyclerView or a NestedScrollView. Oddly, I didn't need the app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" attribute on the RecyclerView. And this was inside the Fragment subclass for the ViewPager.

Hmm, let me test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It works now. All I need to do is to switch from `ListView` to `RecyclerView`. You've made one of my best afternoon!