# How to make toolbar hide on scroll android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to make the toolbar on my app disappear when scrolling down on the app. I can't seem to figure it out with my current setup. I was wondering if there was something I could to accomplish this with how my toolbar is set up right now or do I need to redo my toolbar?

I tried to add,

```xml
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
```

because I someone told me to put it in, but it doesn't seem to work.

My toolbar:

```xml
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/global_color_primary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Toolbar needs to be the child of an AppBarLayout for it to be able to hide on scroll. I believe the AppBarLayout must also be contained within a CoordinatorLayout as well.

The answer to this question from a while back has a nice working example: [CoordinatorLayout doesn't hide the actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804037/coordinatorlayout-doesnt-hide-the-actionbar)