# Collapsing views to tab layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I have layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_gray"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstlinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shapeformaintopbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/aura"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/categLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstlinear"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/inboxCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/inboxImg"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/dialog" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InboxText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/topbartextcolor"
                android:text="@string/inbox"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/friendsCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/FriendsImg"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/friends" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/FriendsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/topbartextcolor"
                android:text="@string/friends"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/profileCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfileImg"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ProfileText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/topbartextcolor"
                android:text="@string/profile"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/categLinear"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/inboxrecycler" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/categLinear"
        android:background="@color/main_gray"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/purple"
        android:padding="140dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it looks like this :

[image]

There is a fragment inside the FrameLayout and recyclerview inside that fragment.
So I want to collapse theese three cardviews to a tab layout when I scroll and reappear cardviews when I scroll to top, but I am not that good at material design. How may I do that?

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804037/coordinatorlayout-doesnt-hide-the-actionbar)?

Comment: @Marat yes I have tried that one,  but its just creating tab layout at the top and doesnt hide when i scroll to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. BIG THANKS to [CTSN](https://github.com/CTSN)

I found it on github. Link:
https://github.com/CTSN/TestCollapsingToolbarLayout